# A sentence with that: grammatical?

Tags: grammar, tense, clauses

"Tom talked about the phenomenon that youngsters like going shopping nowadays has sparked off a debate." Is this sentence grammatically correct? First, I would like to know whether that can connect two clauses like that. Without the last part "has sparked off a debate", it's probably correct.

Second, I reckon the tense use is correct despite three tenses in a sentence, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: No, your text isn't syntactically valid. The actual assertion *Tom talked about the phenomenon that youngsters like going shopping nowadays* is a perfectly good ***sentence***, but you can't use that as the ***subject*** in the construction ***[Something]** has sparked off a debate*. I don't know what you're getting at about verb tenses, but treating this as a "proofreading" exercise (Off Topic), I would suggest changing ***phenomenon*** to ***fact***, then insert COMMA + ***which*** after ***nowadays*** (which imho is a bit "folksy", so I'd change that to ***today*** as well).

Comment: No. It's not grammatical.  The tenses aren't the problem. The usual way to construct something like this would be to say "[Something happened], **which** has sparked off a debate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered (I believe correctly) in the comments:

No the sentence is not grammatical. The tenses aren't the problem. The usual way to construct something like this would be to say "[Something happened], *which* has sparked off a debate".   Add the pronoun "which".

The actual assertion "Tom talked about the phenomenon that youngsters like going shopping nowadays" is a perfectly good sentence. But you can't use that as the subject in the construction "[Something] has sparked off a debate."

> I reckon the tense use is correct despite three tenses in a sentence

In a long sentence that includes various parts, there is no rule whatsoever that all the tenses must match. Consider: "He said, that they will go".  Past + future.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "He said that they would go" as an indirect statement?

Comment: @hellokitty it appears that modifying the tense in reported speech is called backshifting.   Researching this topic, backshifting can be optional.  Is it _required_ that "they will go" _must_ be switched to "they would go", no matter what?  A grammar question...  I think it depends on the situation and the choice of the speaker.

Comment: I get it now;).

Answer (score 0):

This particular use of 'that' (at least, as far as I can tell) is as a pronoun to introduce a restrictive relative clause, for example "*the phenomenon **that** caused the dinosaurs to die out*".

But your whole statement is an ungrammatical mess. What *is* the phenomenon - that 'youngsters like shopping', or that there is a debate about it? There is no point in addressing your supplemental question about tenses unless it made sense.

Comment: I don't understand your words.